# Inferring the return type of an extension method from its use as a method parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, extension-methods, type-inference

I am trying to understand why the generic type can be inferred in the one instance but not the other. Returning the method group off of the object allows for the inference I am trying to make, however using an extension method to return the method group prevents the inference... See the "Works" "Doesn't Work" comments below.

The error is `The type arguments for the method DoKungFoo<TFoo, TTarget>(Foo<TFoo>) cannot be inferred from the usage`

Thanks for any input!

```
    public class Foo<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TTarget> KungFoo<TTarget>(IEnumerable<TTarget> type)
        {
            return type;
        }
    }

    public static class FooExtensions
    {
        public static Func<IEnumerable<TTarget>, IEnumerable<TTarget>> DoKungFoo<TFoo, TTarget>(this Foo<TFoo> foo)
        {
            if(foo == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return foo.KungFoo;
        }
    }

    public class Driver()
    {
        public void Test(Foo<Bar> foo)
        {
            //Works
            Bed(foo.KungFoo);

            //Doesn't Work
            Bed(foo.DoKungFoo())
        }

        public void Bed(Func<IEnumerable<Baz>, IEnumerable<Baz>> func)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {

    }

    public class Baz
    {

    }
```

Comment: `foo.DoKungFoo()` is *called* without any type information provided. The compiler doesn't infer types from the surrounding context, only inner context. `foo.KungFoo` is a *method group* and the type argument can be resolved when converting that to a delegate instance.

Comment: Sad another way, type inference is only for parameters, not return types. `foo.DoKungFoo()` has no parameters to infer types from.

Comment: Type inference doesn't work inside-out. The compiler must be able to determine the type of the expression `foo.DoKungFoo()` *in all circumstances*, *regardless of context*. It can't be `T` one moment and `U` the next. Hence, the fact that you use it as an argument to `Bed` is of no consequence. It's a little easier to see why if you imagine how this would interact with overload resolution if this was not the case -- a complicated feedback loop could be necessary to infer both the type of `DoKungFoo` and the correct overload of `Bed`. `TFoo` is inferrable, `TTarget` is not.